# Is real voltage always the real part of complex voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, complex-numbers

If I have a complex voltage $V_z$, is real voltage $V$ (i.e. the voltage used in the normal ohms law and the voltage 
we normally talk about) always given by $V=Re(V_z)$? And if it is not the case, how do we find $V$ from $V_z$?

Does the same apply to current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A voltage or current given as a complex constant is a [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor).  A voltage given as the complex constant $V_z$ represents the real voltage

$$V(t) = \operatorname{Re} \left( V_z e^{i\omega t} \right)\ \ ,$$

where $\omega$ is the voltage's angular frequency and $t$ is time.

Currents represented as phasors work the same way.